# React Native Text style (e.g. color, fontSize) are not working

Tags: react-native

I am developing with a specified android device, and nearly all the text styles are not working normally.

Here is My code:

```
// App.js
import React from 'react';
import { Text } from 'react-native;

export default () => {
    return (
        <Text style={{
            textShadowOffset: { width: 10, height: 10 },
            textShadowColor: 'red',
            textTransform: 'uppercase',
            marginTop: 100,
            fontFamily: 'Helvetica',
            fontWeight: 'bold',
            textAlign: 'center',
            color: '#FFFFFF',
            fontSize: 100,
            fontStyle: 'italic',
            textDecorationLine: 'underline',
            borderColor: 'green',
            borderWidth: 1,
            lineHeight: 80
        }}>
            test
        </Text>
    );
}
```

```
// entry index.js
import { AppRegistry } from 'react-native';
import App from './src/App';
import { name as appName } from './app.json';

AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => App);
```

I tried the code with android emulator and give me a correct result:
[image]

But if I try it on the specified Android devices, somethings wrong:
[image]

You can see that, only `marginTop`, `borderColor`, `borderWidth` and `lineHeight` work.

Dose someone have any idea?

- react 16.6.3
- react-native 0.58.0
- android 8.1.0

Comment: please provide code for the screen/container.

Comment: I test at the topmost App.js

Comment: In App.js , just see if you are importing the text properly like import Text from 'components/Text' or something similar and not using the inbuilt text component from react-native

Comment: OK, I import the Text component from 'react-native'. and the parent of App.js is the AppRegistry,   which is a blank project

Comment: Would you like to define it as a class?

Comment: u need to use your component not from react-native

Comment: @hong develop   Defining as a class won't help.

Comment: @Wolverine  you mean I should not use react-native component directly??

Comment: oh sorry man .. i thought u defined text in a different class. But its in app.js so it should work

Comment: @Wolverine  thx for your interest.  I dont know why it is not working on the devices. Maybe it is android issue not RN

Answer (score 1):

The problem might be  with your `lineHeight: 80` OR `marginTop`. Try this

```
 <Text style={{
            textShadowOffset: { width: 10, height: 10 },
            textShadowColor: 'red',
            textTransform: 'uppercase',
            fontFamily: 'Helvetica',
            fontWeight: 'bold',
            textAlign: 'center',
            color: '#FFFFFF',
            fontSize: 100,
            fontStyle: 'italic',
            textDecorationLine: 'underline',
            borderColor: 'green',
            borderWidth: 1,
            lineHeight: 80
        }}>
            test
        </Text>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    fontSize: 16,
    alignSelf: 'center',
    fontFamily: Fonts.semibold,
    color: Colors.primary,
```

Comment: Please comment or explain your code so the person you are trying to help can understand what the code does and how it solves their problem.